# Hugo : How to translate group name in URLs

Tags: internationalization, hugo

I'm struggling with something that is probably simple.

I created a new page type under layouts:

```
layouts
 |--- PageType
   |--- list.html
   |--- single.html
```

Under content I have the following structure:

```
content
 |--- English
   |--- PageType
     |--- first.md
     |--- second.md
 |--- French
   |--- PageType
     |--- first.md
     |--- second.md
```

Up to this point all works great. Now when it comes to i18n, I know I can use `slug` font matter in the `*.md` files, but how do I change the `PageType` that appears in the translated URL?

English:

- http://localhost:1111/PageType/
- http://localhost:1111/PageType/first/

French (not what I want):

- http://localhost:1111/fr/PageType/
- http://localhost:1111/fr/PageType/premier/

Desired French:

- http://localhost:1111/fr/TypeDePage/
- http://localhost:1111/fr/TypeDePage/premier/

Comment: I'm not sure if it breaks anything in terms of `i18n` but I was able to accomplish this by adding an `_index.md` file in the folder, translated the folder name (menu entry is defined in config.toml) & by specifying the `type` in the front matter of each of my pages.